# Problemas com acentuação

Tags: banco-de-dados, utf-8

Já visitei diversos sites e o StackOverflow foi o principal deles, em que eram propostas diversas soluções para problemas de acentuação nas páginas. Percebi que eu havia configurado meu banco de dados errado (utf8-bin) e minha página estava com charset ISO-8859-1. Corrigi e já tentei de tudo mas o meu cabeçalho continua exibindo caracteres estranhos como o abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu cabeçalho está assim:

```
<?php
        $title = BD::conn()->prepare("SELECT `title`, `id`, `keywords`, `description` FROM `pags` WHERE `id` = ? LIMIT 0 , 1");
        $title->execute(array($pag));
        $dados = $title->fetch();
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title><?php echo $dados['title']; ?> - Gopinatha &reg;</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

Meu banco está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha tabela está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E o campo em questão está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como está fazendo a conexão com o banco ?

Comment: Olá Raoni, vou editar o posto para colocar a conexão também

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que na base de dados não permite acentuação mas permite uns caracteres especiais que os substituem.

Recomendo [este site](http://www.cafewebmaster.com/online_tools/utf8_encode). Na caixa de cima escreva o texto da base de dados, depois converta e cole na base de dados e ficará direito.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta colocar um header antes do seu html, assim:

```
<?php
       header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
       setlocale(LC_TIME, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese');
       date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
?>

    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title><?php echo $dados['title']; ?> - Gopinatha &reg;</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Victor, mas também não funcionou...

Comment: Tira esse meta: <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
e o "<meta charset="utf-8">" substitui por "<meta charset="UTF-8">"

Comment: Também não deu certo. :/